# Java Stack.peek() to objects

Tags: java, class, stack, peek

I am attempting to use a stack to put objects in a stack. I have a Pixel class that has a simple getX function that returns a variable defined in the constructor. When I use the stack.peek().getX(); it says that it cannot find the symbol for .getX();

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
Pixel first = new Pixel(colorX,colorY);

stack.push(first);

int x = stack.peek().getX();
```

Am I using the peek function wrong? Or do I have my Pixel class setup incorrectly?

```
public class Pixel {
private int x, y , count = 0;

Pixel(int x_in, int y_in)
{
    x = x_in; 
    y = y_in;
}

public int getX(){return x;}
public int getY(){return y;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *because* you are using a raw `Stack`, instead of `Stack<Pixel>` that you get this error.  A raw stack is essentially equivalent to `Stack<Object>`, so when you call `peek()` it returns `Object` and not `Pixel`.

Even though the runtime type may be `Pixel`, method resolution happens at compile time and `Object` has no `getX()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your stack with `Stack stack = new Stack();`, but the definition of the stack class has a parameter type Stack. By not declaring the type, as is possible due to Java not always having had the generics, you basically wrote `Stack<?>`, so the compiler doesn't know which methods the returned value will have.

How to solve? Declare your stack as `Stack<Pixel> stack = new Stack<>();`